# Lego Mindstorms EV3: Making a bot go straight with Gyro

Tags: lego-mindstorms

I've been trying to use `Lego EV3` with a gyro sensor to make it go straight. I've tried many videos, but they don't seem to work. Here's my code
[image]

Answer (score 2):

to start off, your multiplier seems a little too off, usually I do something like 2.

You might want to refer to the image in the link below.

[Gyro programming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5G7w.png)

I usually use this as my base gyro programming. If you understand My Blocks, I am basically using that in my programme. All I have to do is to add in the values in terms of direction, speed and distance.

Feel free to ask me if you need further help!